# Combine the result of multiple SQL select queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have fields as open_date and a close_date. I have to create a procedure for which, given a range of dates as input, I show all the records for each date that lies within the range, the records whose open_date>date and closed_date

for example if my table is

```
id   open_date    closed_date
1    2016-06-06   2016-06-10
2    2016-06-08   2016-06-11
```

and the range of dates is 2016-06-07 to 2016-06-09

then the result should be

```
Date          Count
2016-06-07      1
2016-06-08      2
2016-06-09      2
```

But the result that I am getting is

```
 Date          Count
2016-06-09      2
```

The procedure that I have written down is given below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_number_of_bugs`(IN startDate DateTIme, IN endDate DateTime)
BEGIN
Declare testDate Date;
SET testDate=startDate;
while testDate<=endDate DO
select testDate as Dates ,count(bugID) as Number_Of_Bugs_Open from bugs where testDate between open_date and close_date OR close_date=null;
SET testDate=DATE_ADD(testDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END while;
END
```

I guess I have to combine the results from the multiple select statements that
run throgh the while loop. Please suggest me a way to do that.

Comment: Removed `SQL SERVER` tag

Comment: Why the WHILE loop. Surely thats a simple single query

Comment: Do you have calendar table ?

Comment: 8 8 ?? Shouldn't that be 8 9 ?? And I don't understand the count either.

Comment: Your required results do not seem to match your inputs?? Please check! Why would you want 2 results for date=2016-06-08

Comment: If am not wrong last should be `2016-06-09      2`

Comment: @RiggsFolly How can it be done without the loop?

Comment: @NehaArora - Do you have calendar table ?

Comment: @prdp No, I don't.

Comment: @NehaArora - Then create it will be very useful while handling requests like your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are gutting all the results but in multiple result sets.
You can save all query results in a temporary table and query it once at the end.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `find_number_of_bugs`(IN startDate DateTIme, IN endDate DateTime)
BEGIN
Declare testDate Date;
SET testDate=startDate;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE output (Dates date,Number_Of_Bugs_Open int);

while testDate<=endDate DO

insert into output select testDate as Dates ,count(bugID) as Number_Of_Bugs_Open from bugs where testDate between open_date and close_date OR close_date=null;

SET testDate=DATE_ADD(testDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END while;

select * from output;

END
```

Comment: @NehaArora,  P.s. if you liked the answer you might want to upvote

Comment: I don't have reputation enough to do that :D